# Update python 3.5 in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed python 3.5 with the following commando:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda
```

I also have a base Anaconda python27 installed. When I wish to update it I just write:

```
conda update conda
```

But how do I update my pyhon35?

I have tried this:

```
activate py35
[py35] C:\Users\trofl>cd C:\Users\trofl\Anaconda2\envs\py35

[py35] C:\Users\trofl\Anaconda2\envs\py35>conda install conda
    Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
    Fetching package metadata: ....
    Solving package specifications: .........

    Error: 'conda' can only be installed into the root environment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to install when you have conda-env and conda-build in your current environment. You have to remove these first to update conda.

```
source activate my-env
conda remove conda-build
conda remove conda-env
conda update anaconda
```