# conda install - six, wheel, numpy, protobuf, werkzeug

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I installed conda version of opencv - opencv 3.2 + python 3.4.3 .
after that i tried to install tensorflow using

```
# For Python 3.4
    wget https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/releases/download/v1.1.0/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_armv7l.whl
    sudo pip3 install tensorflow-1.1.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_armv7l.whl
```

It is asking for specific versions of six, wheel, numpy, protobuf, werkzeug
and it is uninstalling the packges and reinstalling with specific versions. but when I tried to import in python it is showing

```
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I think the reinstalling process is done by pip and the conda is not recognizing it.

**update:** This is my installed conda list.

[image: conda list]

I need a command to install the below packages with conda

```
six >= version 1.10.0 
wheel >= version 0.26 
numpy >= version 1.11.0 
protobuf >= version 3.2.0 
werkzeug >= version 0.11.10
```

My conda version is conda 3.16.0

**update:**

I found the package using

```
anaconda search -t conda six
```

required package is marked in red colour in the pic1

[image: pic1]

Next I have done

```
anaconda show vpython/six
```

it is showing my required version. when I install using the given command

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/vpython six
```

only the  older version is installing. I need a solution to install the version I want.

I also tried all other packages, it is also installing the same old version.
I have also given you the exact version I want.

[image: pic2]

update: All the above packages needs to be installed in armv7l platform.

Comment: @api55 help me to solve this error bro or suggest any one who is well intelligent in this kind of stuffs

Comment: check in conda documentation and try using conda install package. If you are unsure about name and version on package try conda search package_name(some alphabets which you are sure of which exists).

Comment: `conda list` will also give you the list of all the packages currently installed along with their version number.

Comment: @ Ayush Kesarwani @Eskapp I have done all that searches but that specific version is not available. I have given the required version can u hep me with the commands to install it

Comment: I think you should integrate all the comments you added to the accepted answer to your question (edit your question, make clear what you tried, the error messages). This will help people you stubble across the same issue in the future. Have you tried the last command you found? `conda install -c tballance six` I think `-c` is kinda similar to `--channel`, so if you haven't tried yet to look at the package on `tballance`, try this new command.

Comment: @Eskapp plz check the updated question. the command u have given is of no use, it is also showing the same old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated all the above requested packages by myself.
To find all the above packages using conda we need to use the below commands,

```
anaconda search –t conda <package name>
```

After you found your package,

```
anaconda show <package(owner/package)>
```

It will display the version and will provide the installation command
Give the command and press enter.

six:

```
anaconda show krrishnarraj/six
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/krrishnarraj six
```

wheel:

```
conda install wheel
```

numpy:

```
pip install numpy
```

protobuf:

```
pip install protobuf
```

werkzeug:

```
pip install werkzeug
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command line you ask for:

`conda install package=version`

`package` is the name of the module you want to install
`version` is the version number (like `1.2.3`)

Comment: And when conda doesn't find a package on its current channel, try `conda install --channel conda-forge package` (it'll get the last version automatically, or you can specify it as explained)
I noticed that usually conda-forge is more up-to-date than the default channel.

Comment: @Eskapp Bro it is not showing the required version,  i did this                                              
~ $ conda install --channel conda-forge six
Fetching package metadata: ......
Solving package specifications: ...........
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/pi/miniconda3:
#
six                       1.9.0                    py34_0
 it is showing the version i already have

Comment: @Eskapp when i tried search the specific version it is showing                                
~ $ conda install --channel conda-forge six=1.10.0
Fetching package metadata: ......
Error: No packages found in current linux-armv7l channels matching: six 1.10|1.10.0*

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda six 1.10|1.10.0*
 i did that too found 0 packages

Comment: @Eskapp my required version is available in anaconda cloud                 link:https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/six        when i tried to install it is showing                                                                                                        ~ $ conda install -c conda-forge six
Fetching package metadata: ........
Solving package specifications: ...........
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/pi/miniconda3:
#
six                       1.9.0                    py34_0

Comment: @Eskapp i have found my package in this link how can i install it.                https://anaconda.org/tballance/six

Comment: @voli if this answer does not fully solve your issue, do not mark it as accepted. People will not come to see your question if they see it is already answered and you have far less chances to get new people help you.

Comment: This answer answers the question asked Eskapp - clearly, new and/or additional questions require opening a new question.

Comment: Trying to answer additional requests in the comments is not the way to go.
@Voli, if you have further problems, please open a new question.

Comment: @Reblochon Masque I am new to this bro. the above answer is not helping me.

Comment: ?? your question is: "I need a command to install the below packages with conda" -- which is precisely what I gave you !

Comment: @Reblochon Masque that answer command is giving the old version  conda install package . when i give the version, it is showing no packages found.

Comment: @Reblochon Masque plz check my updated question.

Comment: No. you should contact the conda people and ask them why they don't provide you with the version you "want"!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install the package `six` version `1.10.0` with conda  version `4.3.23` and Python 3.5.

I suggest that you update your conda: `conda - conda update`

If you still cannot get the version of `six` you need, install Python 3.5 (or 3.6). (Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710370/update-python-3-5-in-anaconda) if you have trouble installing it.)

Comment: bro give the command u tetsed.

Comment: I want the armv7l platform packages.